# Unregister an register panels with python

Tags: python, add-on, panel

The following script is part of a bigger addon that creates panels procedurally to a given category. The problem that I am dealing with is that when I remove the addon that also contains this script then all panels are getting removed besides the panels created by this script. So how can I register and unregister all of them correctly? Because I am not a coder I would love to see an example script of how I have to change it. Thank you!

```
import bpy

category = CategoryY

def create_node_panel(node, order):
class MyNodePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = f"{node.name}"
    bl_idname = f"NODE_PT_{node.name.replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_').replace('.', '_').replace('(', '_').replace(')', '').replace('/', '_')}"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = category
    bl_order = order

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        if node is None:
            layout.label(text="Node not found")
            return

        inputs = [input for input in node.inputs if input.enabled and not input.hide_value and not input.is_linked]
        box = layout.box()
        for input in inputs:
            box.prop(node.inputs[input.name], "default_value", text=input.name)

        if "OBJSpecific" in self.bl_label:
            sub_box = box.box()
            row = sub_box.row()
            row.alignment = 'CENTER'
            row.scale_x = 1
            row.scale_y = 1
            row.label(text='Pointerobject', icon_value=78 )
            sub_box.prop(bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes[node.name].node_tree,  'sna_pointerobjmask',text='')
            sub_box.operator('sna.clearpasses_fe83e', text='Clear All Passes', icon_value=3,    emboss=True, depress=False)

return MyNodePanel

nodes = LISTINPUT
order = 4
for node in nodes:
panel_class = create_node_panel(node, order)
bpy.utils.register_class(panel_class)
order += 1
```

Comment: How would one replicate the issue you describe? Could you edit the question and share full code and steps required to replicate the issue? See the "UI Panel" example in the Text Editor's Templates -> Python menu. Why would using `bpy.utils.unregister_class()` like in that example not work for you?